# command not found handle doesn't work for url

Tags: bash, command, url

I'm trying to setup the command_not_found_handle for URL links,

```
%> command_not_found_handle() { echo "OK"; }
%> aaaaa
OK
%> http://www.google.com
bash: http://www.google.com: No such file or directory
```

So it works for normal input, but not URL links, any ideas?

Comment: `command_not_found_handle` only triggers for PATH lookups, and a URL doesn't trigger a PATH lookup. I think you'd have to patch bash (though maybe you can do something with a debug trap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

URLs are treated as containing subdirectories. E.g. see this:

```
$ command_not_found_handle() { echo "OK"; }
$ aaa
OK
$ aaa/bbb
bash: aaa/bbb: No such file or directory
$
```

That is, it works when you run a command, but then when you run a command with a slash, it likely tries to do `bbb` in folder `aaa`. The same happens with URLs - it considers it running the command `www.google.com` within the directory `http:`.

From the bash man page:

> If  the  name  is  neither a shell function nor a builtin, **and
>   contains no slashes**, bash searches each element of the PATH for a
>   directory containing an executable
>          file by that name.  Bash uses a hash table to remember the full pathnames of executable files (see hash under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS
>   below).  A full search of  the
>          directories  in  PATH is performed only if the command is not found in the hash table.  If the search is unsuccessful, the shell
>   searches for a defined shell func‐
>          tion named command_not_found_handle.  If that function exists, it is invoked with the original command and the original command's
>   arguments as its  arguments,  and
>          the  function's exit status becomes the exit status of the shell.  If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error
>   message and returns an exit status of
>          127.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: @thewpfguy Except what [Gilles suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101495/command-not-found-handle-doesnt-work-for-url/101502?noredirect=1#comment154807_101495), I don't think there's a solution that supports using slashes.